# Pass data from parent to children using XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: swift3, xlpagertabstrip

My problem is:

I have a viewControllers A and B. I go from A to B using a segue.

viewController B has two children (B1 and B2) and both need the same data passed from A.

How can I pass data from A to child B1 and B2?

At that moment I can only pass data to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to pass the data to the `UIViewController` B from the `UIViewController` A via the segue.

Afterwards, in the `UIViewController` B, when you implement the method `override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]` you should create B1 and B2 controllers. After the creation of them, you should set the pertinent information to each one.

```
var data = "The data passed from A"

override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]
    let firstChild = B1()
    let secondChild = B2()
    firstChild.data = self.data
    secondChild.data = self.data
    return [firstChild, secondChild]
}
```

Hope it helps!